# Python program with argument containing $

Tags: python

I have a python program which accepts an argument. But when I am passing an argument value containing `"$6"`, it is not printing inside the program.

```
import argparse,ast

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("password")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.password
```

While invoking the program as

> python main.py main$6hhh

I am getting response as `"mainhhh"` only. Why is this behaviour?

Comment: Your shell interprets `$6hhh`as variable and returns an empty string for it. Try `python main.py 'main$6hhh'`instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command Line interprets `$6hhh` as a variable. Enclose it in single quotes, so your command would be:

```
python main.py 'main$6hhh'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `bash` interprets $6 as a positional parameter, but it has no 6th argument, so it inserts nothing.